# How to add a shortcode to an HTML image tag

Tags: shortcode

I want to add a timestamp to use as unique id for conversion tracking.

I have a `[[timestamp]]` shortcode on my site. In text it works fine, but the shortcode does not work when placed inside the `src` attribute of an image tag, e.g.:

```
<img src="http://example.com/transaction_id=[[timestamp]]">
```

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

The shortcode I use:

```
// Do TimeStamper Shortcode ( timestamper() ) 
function timestamper( $atts ){

  if (!is_admin()) {
    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11);
  }
  $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  return $time;
}

add_shortcode( 'timestamp', 'timestamper' );
```

I put the shortcode in the html code:

```
`<img src="http://oa1.nl/m/4521/cf039315e6a96f616cc0fe87f861fc640b0f3327/?transactie_id=[timestamp]" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; border: 0px;”>`
```

As you can see  [here](http://isolatiegilde.nl/isolatie-offertes-aanvragen/bedankpagina-lh) in the output the shortcode is not replaced by the time. In text (the numbers you see on the page) it works fine but below the text there is the image code (you can not see the image, only in code, because it is 1 x 1 pixel item). I attached a printscreen of the source code:  [image: the code on output]

Comment: Shortcodes only need one opening and closing bracket, e.g. `[timestamp]`. Would you please explain what you mean by *doesn't work*, and please add the PHP used for generating the shorcode's output.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate function to enable shortcodes in the text widget because trying to do so within the shortcode function itself is too late.

```
// Enable the use of shortcodes within the text widget.
function wpse249090_widget_text_enable_shortcodes() {
    add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse249090_widget_text_enable_shortcodes' );

// Do TimeStamper Shortcode ( timestamper() ) 
function timestamper( $atts ) {
  $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  return $time;
}
add_shortcode( 'timestamp', 'timestamper' );
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with some code to refine my problem...

Comment: Hello, Wilfred. Thank you for the update. I've updated my answer based on the new information.